# use timeWindow and processingTime but data Ingestion was blockd

Tags: apache-flink

When I use Windows All, because there is only one degree of parallelism, there is a bottleneck in processing. Therefore, I change to timeWindow and use processTime, but I encounter a new problem, data can not be ingested. From the log on the console, it can be seen that only more than ten data are processed every second, if I use Windows All. It can process tens of thousands of data per second. So I don't know why.

When I added waterMark to time Windows, I found that time Windows can handle a large number of data per second, but upstream data still accumulates

```
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<DataSetPOJO> dataSetPOJOSingleOutputStreamOperator = sdkInfos.flatMap(...);

        dataSetPOJOSingleOutputStreamOperator.keyBy(new KeySelector<DataSetPOJO, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(DataSetPOJO dataSet) {
                return dataSet.getPartitionKey();
            }
        }).timeWindow(Time.seconds(3))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<DataSetPOJO, List<DataSetPOJO>, String, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<DataSetPOJO> elements,
                                        Collector<List<DataSetPOJO>> out) throws Exception {
                        ArrayList<DataSetPOJO> dataSetPOJO = Lists.newArrayList(elements);
                        if (dataSetPOJO.size() > 0) {
//                            log.info("key~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:" + key);
//                            log.info("dataSetPOJO.size():" + dataSetPOJO.size());
                            out.collect(dataSetPOJO);
                        }
                    }
                }).addSink(new Sink2Postgre());
```

I hope I can save enough batches in windows to write PostgreSQL,If this is not correct, how to write, if it is no problem, what will be the problem. Fink Version 1.5.3

Comment: Hey, what is `PartitionKey`  in Your case ? If there are too many keys, the windows may accumulate and this can cause an issue.